# Migrate mariadb data from one server to other

Tags: mariadb, new-operator, migrate

Migration mariadb data from one linux server to other one

Good Morning,

I am performing a process of migrating all the data contained in a linux mariadb server to a new linux mariadb server.

The problem I am encountering is that, I can migrate all the data from all the databases I have, using mysqldump --all-databases, but what I can't do or can't find a way to do is also obtain the information from Users with their corresponding permissions and password. I have many users that I have to migrate and I don't want to create new users one by one on the new server. Is there any way to also import users, permissions and passwords?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Might help: [Backup/Restore Users/Passwords/Privileges](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/100516/186508)

Answer (score 0):

When you dump all the data with `mysqldump --all-databases`, it includes the `mysql.user` table, which contains all the users and hashed passwords already.

So on your new server, when you import the output of `--all-databases`, it will bring all your users with it, as it overwrites the new server's `mysql.user` table during the import.

You can further confirm with phpmyadmin afterwards, browsing to the `mysql` database and the `user` table.